# NetBeans constantly adds JacksonJsonProvider to my JAX-RS ApplicationConfig class

Tags: netbeans

NetBeans (7.3.1 Build 201306052037) is constantly adding the following lines to my JAX-RS ApplicationConfig class. I don't want these lines added so how do I tell it to stop?

```
        // following code can be used to customize Jersey 1.x JSON provider:
    try {
        Class jacksonProvider = Class.forName("org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider");
        resources.add(jacksonProvider);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Netbeans' webservice plugin (see [this thread](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231003)). It will be fixed in version 7.4 of the IDE.